# How to reload a blf font id when user changes theme?

Tags: python, scripting

1. Suppose you draw some text in viewport via `draw_handler_add`

[image]

```
import bpy, blf

font_path = 'D:\\some.ttf'      # <-- choose your font here
font_id = blf.load(font_path)

def draw_callback_px():
    blf.position(font_id, 20, 20, 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 50.0)
    blf.draw(font_id, "BLF")

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

2. When the user changes the theme in the UI, the text disappears **(unexpected results)** until the font ID is reloaded.

[image]

So, How to catch the theme changes and then reload the font id?

```
import bpy, blf

font_path = 'D:\\some.ttf'      # <-- choose your font here
font_id = blf.load(font_path)

def draw_callback_px():
    blf.position(font_id, 20, 20, 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 50.0)
    blf.draw(font_id, "BLF")

def when_theme_changed():    # <------- Need to run when theme changes
    print('Theme change detected')
    global font_id
    font_id = blf.load(font_path)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```